# Different CSS for td which contains another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have **a html table inside a html table**. I want to apply different css style (padding and margin) **for the particular td which contains the child table alone**.

I want `padding: 5px;` for all td's except the one which contains child table. I cant explicitly give the styling to td's as the **table is generated dynamically**. Sometimes the parent table will have child table and sometimes not. I have tried the same with jQuery but not able to resolve the issue.

The parent table is generated as a part of GridView (asp.net) and am using EmptyDataTemplate to create a child table look alike the same GridView for inserting values if no data exists.

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: and what have you tried!

Comment: Just add a line at the child table's insertion function and select the target (td here) parent .

Comment: I've learnt that nested tables are bad practice, has this changed lately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this example I made](http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/p8enwvf8/1/):

```
td table {
    margin: -5px;
}
```

The trick is to give the 2nd table a negative margin to counteract the padding surrounding it.

Comment: Hi Austin, thanks for your answer. I also tried the same, but the problem is, on the right side of the child table there is almost 10px of empty space with respect to parent table. Even if I give width as 100% its not changing.

Comment: I'd have to see an example of what you're talking about because I'm not seeing a gap in the version I created: http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/p8enwvf8/2/

Comment: I am using GridView (asp.net) and the child table is inside the GridView. Anyways except that gap everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in jquery :

```
$("td").not($(this).find("table")).css("padding","5px");
```

This will add padding to all td that does not have a table has child. You can also do this by adding a class instead of inline style.

Comment: but this affects child table's tds too

Comment: Yes, if the child table has a child table.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at css selectors [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html)

although waht you describe is not part of CSS yet i guess [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/)

If you can use JQuery on your table td with a sub-table sub: `$('table td:has(table.sub)').addClass('has_sub');`

Then style the `td.has_sub`

Answer (score 0):

Target it with something like below

**CSS**

```
 .the-class {
enter code here

}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("td:has(table)").addClass("the-class");
```

**Note:** I prefer **addClass** method because **.css** adds an inline css to your html.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, the selector you are looking for is ">" which points to a child element, but not grandchild.
Example:

```
parent-selector > direct-child-selector {
}
```

For the tables though it's a bit tricky as html inserts tbody automatically so what you need is:

```
table-selector > tbody > tr > td {
}
```